# Change in position when wrap content

Tags: android, android-imageview

When I am changing `width` and `height` to `wrap_content` of `ImageView` their position also changes?? Any solution that I only want to `wrap_content` `height` and `width` but position of `view` remains same

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ammm">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/t1"
                android:tag="p"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@color/black"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/t2"
                android:tag="r"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/t1" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/t3"
                android:tag="q"
                android:background="@color/brown"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/t2" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:id="@+id/t4"
                android:tag="r"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/t3" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you show your xml with the imageview in it ?

Answer (score 0):

try this use `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ammm"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:tag="p" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/t2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:tag="r" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/t3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:tag="q" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/t4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:tag="r" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want width and height 100dp but after drag want to change it to wrap_content but after doing wrap_content its position changes